# Why isn't mdfind finding my wsdl files?

Tags: macos, grep

Looks like for me that mdfind did not find all results or matches.

Executing from the same directory:

```
grep "https://payout" -R .                                                                              
./withdrawal.wsdl:      <soap:address location="https://www.api.com/8001/Customer.asmx" />
./withdrawal.wsdl:      <soap12:address location="https://www.api.com/8001/Customer.asmx" />
./withdrawal.wsdl:      <http:address location="https://www.api.com/8001/Customer.asmx" />
./withdrawal.wsdl:      <http:address location="https://www.api.com/8001/Customer.asmx" />

mdfind  "https://payout" -onlyin .
```

No hidden stuff:

```
ls -Ol withdrawal.wsdl                                                                                  
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff  - 21637 Apr 21 23:00 withdrawal.wsdl
```

I experienced this in multiple cases and had not found any cause to it.
Do somebody has an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a bug.

`mdfind` can only search files that have been indexed by Spotlight. For a file to be indexed, there needs to be a Spotlight importer for its filetype. Unless you've explicitly installed an indexer for WSDL files, these files are unlikely to be indexed.

Comment: Can you find them if you search for `https://payout` in the Spotlight search bar?  If not, then they haven't been indexed, and `mdfind` won't find them.

Comment: so the problem was with the file type. I see, however mdfind was able to find one WSDL files but not the other... I could show a test case from this also.

However it makes much more sense so I give a + 1 : )